# Show output from .net service in a monitor application

Tags: c#, logging, service

I have several running .net service processes and now I want to write a monitor application where the user can see all services and what they are currently doing.

The service write their output to a log file/event log.
The monitor application should present the services (this is easy) and then the user can choose on of the service and sees what the service is doing.
My idea was to poll the logfile (or set a FileSystemWatcher on it) and reload the logfile all the times.

Is there a better way / what are the alternatives?

e.g.

Is is possible to connect to the service process and the service process raises events (with the logtext) to the monitor application process (in Win32 I did that long ago, but I don´t know how to do that in .net)?

Or write to shared memory?

Or is is possible to pass messages through the C# ServiceController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, youre service can write its messages into any kind of logger interface. Let's call it `IServiceLogger` which provides a method like `Log(string message)`. Imaging that your service has a list of loggers implementing this interface and writes into each of them.

With this, you can plug any implementation of that interface to retrieve the logs from the service. So this could be an `ServiceFileLogger` implementation to write into the file system as well as a `NetworkLogger` which sends those log messages to all connected clients.

Regarding the `NetworkLogger`, you still have to do some work to handle the connection between the monitoring clients and  the server (the process which receives the logs and sends them to the clients) but you could build really smart monitoring tools and deploy them in your company network or even build a website showing live logs.

**Tip:**
If you want a more standardized solution, I'd highly recommend to take a look at **log4net** which basically does the same internally but has a huge set of features on top. With **log4net** you can use (or create) a bunch of different [log appenders](http://www.beefycode.com/post/log4net-tutorial-pt-3-appenders.aspx) which receive these messages and can process them further like writing emails, inserting into a database, writing into files, etc. So I think you can find a matching appender or create your own for your monitoring clients.

Comment: Hello, I already use log4net and i wrapped it in my own LoggingManager, because I already write to different devices (Eventlog, Console, file) I came not up with the idea of appenders, so I wrapped it. This is not the problem, how do I transfer the data (push) to the monitor application, or should the monitor application poll the different devices (logfile, eventlog)

Comment: Assuming that you have a NetworkLogger which receives the logs from the service code, I'd connect the clients to the service with WCF and push the messages back to the clients per tcp duplex channel so that the clients get the logs in realtime. Alternatively, you could use SignalR which is way easier to implement and optimized for pushing or even broadcasting data.

Comment: Thanks, I found some hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32030500/remotingappender-problems-conn-created-but-nothing-appended and after a long fight I got the remote logging with log4net working, but log4net seems not to be a reliable solution. Sometimes the connection is lost and the remote logging does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you can use Windows Communication Foundation. You can expose an event in your service, and your monitor can bind to this event.

This method depends on the implementation, but you can learn about WCF here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712(v=vs.110).aspx